# Getting the first item for a tuple for eaching a row in a list in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm a bit new to Spark and I am trying to do a simple mapping.
My data is like the following:

```
RDD((0, list(tuples)), ..., (19, list(tuples))
```

What I want to do is grabbing the first item in each tuple, so ultimately something like this:

```
RDD((0, list(first item of each tuple),..., (19, list(first item of each tuple))
```

Can someone help me out with how to map this?
I'll appreciate that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `mapValues` to convert the list of tuples to a list of tuple[0]:

```
rdd.mapValues(lambda x: [t[0] for t in x])
```

Comment: Ah yes, this makes total sense. Thanks so much @AChampion

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

`kv` here meaning "key-value" and mapping [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) over the values. So, `map` within a `map` :-)

```
from operator import itemgetter
rdd = sc.parallelize([(0, [(0,'a'), (1,'b'), (2,'c')]), (1, [(3,'x'), (5,'y'), (6,'z')])])
mapped = rdd.mapValues(lambda v: map(itemgetter(0), v))
```

Output

```
mapped.collect()
[(0, [0, 1, 2]), (1, [3, 5, 6])]
```

Comment: Don't think so as this will just return the first item of the list, not the first of every tuple in the list - you would need `(kv[0], [a[0] for a in kv[1]])` but given you are just affecting the values you can use `mapValues()` to simplify

Comment: @cricket_007 I tried what you said already, and it just gives me the first tuple in each tuple.

Comment: @AceHaidrey Yeah, sorry. Fixed with alternate solution